# py2exe 1 missing modules, readline

Tags: module, py2exe

I have problems in py2exe. I simply want to "convert" a .py file into a .exe file, which i can easiely run on my PC, but if i run py2exe a error message appears:

Here is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
setup(console=['filename.py'])
```

And the error message it the following:

```
1 missing Modules
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
Building 'dist\filename.exe'.
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages\\py2exe\\run_w-py3.5-win32.exe'
```

I hope you guys can help me ;)
greetz

Comment: Apparently the problem is that 3.5 isn't supported yet. If you check out the folder of py2exe, youll notice most other versions are available, including 3.4, but not 3.5.

Im running into the exact same issue here

Answer (score 0):

May you should install readline package first.
This package dones't work in Windows by default.
If you are in Windows,You should use **pyreadline** instead of **readline**

```
pip install pyreadline
```

It works to me.